# Why isn't SO_REUSEADDR working for multiprocessing.Listener?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm building an application that communicates with another script using the `Listener/Client` classes of the `multiprocessing` package.

I can successfully create both the listener and client, and communicate, however I am still receiving the lasting effects of the *TCP TIME-WAIT* - after I rerun the script I get the exception when instantiating the listener:

> [Errno 98] Address already in use

I have no idea why this is happening, because as far as I know, by default **SO_REUSEADDR** is set in the constructor for Listener (see [Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py](https://github.com/certik/python-2.7/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L253)).

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This normally happens when you don't close the socket cleanly. Can you post some code showing that you're closing the socket cleanly, even if you force-close your application?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't handled the SIGINT which meant I didn't close the socket - changed this now, works fine.